# Add value to ERC20 token

Tags: ether, tokens, erc-20

I have created an ERC20 token, but how does it get value?

Right now, 100,000,000 BST tokens are worth 0 Ether.

Can someone help me learn how to get the tokens to gain value?

Answer (score 2):

ERC20 tokens do not have any inherent value. If you want to bring value to the token, you must make it something desirable by others. This could be through a utility that the token provides access to, or a security that the token represents, or even building a community that has an irrational love for the token.

If you want the token to have value, people will need to want to buy it, and that is not something you can pull out from thin air.

Comment: Danke für die schnelle Antwort. Aber wenn die Token gekauft werden - Wohin müssen die ETHER transferiert werden? Wird der Wert des Tokens angepasst?

Comment: If you want to create tokens which are specifically tradeable for Ether, you will need to set up a contract to do that. This is outside the ERC20 standard. Take a look at this crowdsale documentation: [Crowdsale: Raising funds from friends without a third party](https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale)